# Handling completion provider quotes

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor for a particular JSON file editing case and am implementing custom completion providers. There's only one unfortunate problem.

If you take a look at the given example: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example, write in `"lod` and auto-complete "lodash" into the field, you'll find that instead of code like

```
{
  dependencies: {
      "lodash": "*"
  }
}
```

one instead ends up with

```
{
  dependencies: {
      ""lodash": "*""
  }
}
```

This is due to the closing quotation being auto-inserted and then not being part of the textUntilPosition.

The auto-completion in the example works nicely if I have yet to write anything and use Ctrl+Space to trigger auto-completion. With something written in, however, I end up with an extra quotation mark at the start and at the end of the auto-completion string.

This cannot be changed even by changing the capture group in the example, it seems. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: So looking at it more, https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitem.html#range can be used to define what is replaced but this is a very limited tool if indeed the range needs to be essentially statically defined.